# Wireless router can't be found from linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, dd-wrt, bridge

I have a very strange problem with my wireless routers, or linux. I have 2 wireless routers one directly connected to my modem (router 1) and another wireless router (router 2) on the 2nd floor connected to router 1 without cables and configured as a repeater bridge. Router 1 is configured to broadcast the ssid and have been set up to use wpa-personal and router 2 has the same configuration as router 1 plus a virtual interface.
I am able to connect to both routers from all my windows boxes, but I fail to connect from linux (I have tried with 2 different laptops without luck). What is very strange is that I can't see the routers when I scan but I am able to see my neighbors routers. I have tried to turn off router 2 to see if it had an impact, but no luck. I know that I am able to connect to a wireless router since I have had success with that at work.

Router 1 is a Siemens se551 (with default firmware) and router 2 is a linksys wrt54g (running DD-WRT build 13064).

Hope that someone can help, so that I can install linux on my new netbook and get rid of Windows 7 starter . . .

Comment: Some more detail such as Linux distro / version would be helpful.

Comment: Well I have tried with different linux distributions, suse 11, ubuntu 9.x, kubuntu 9.x and 10.x and kubuntu 10.x for netbook. It seems as if the fact that I have connected to the router from Windows from the same machine has an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem after installing kismet on the computer and analyzing the results. I found that the routers were set to use channel 13 (it was set to automatic) and an iwlist wlan0 channel reviled that channel 13 was not available. I changed the channel to 1 and now it all works.